# Passing table name as a function parameter in Python/Pandas/PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pandas, prepared-statement

I am trying to call table_name in my SQL query using the 'new' secure way (it is good against SQL injection attacks) as in here: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql
but I can't make it work with my code (table_name is a parameter of my function).

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2 as pg
import pandas.io.sql as psql
from psycopg2 import sql

sql_query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {} limit %d offset %d" % (table_name, chunk_size, offset)).format(sql.Identifier(table_name)) 
df = psql.read_sql_query(sql_query, connection)
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE (after a suggested answer):

I tried with

```
def import_table(self, connection, table_name, chunk_size, offset):
    sql = "SELECT * FROM {} limit %d offset %d" 
    qry = sql.format(**dict(table=table_name)) %(chunk_size, offset)
    df_piece = psql.read_sql_query(qry, connection)
```

And then calling it with:

```
df = pd.concat(import_table(pg.connect("dbname=my_db user=my_user"), 'table_name', 100000, 0))
```

But I am getting an error:

```
---> 30             qry = sql_ct.format(**dict(table=table_name)) %  (chunk_size, offset)
 31             df_piece = psql.read_sql_query(qry, connection)
 32 

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table names/column names can't be parameterized this way.

It can and should be applied to values.

Please read about [Prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

Consider the following technique:

```
# param. for str format:      vvvvv
In [9]: qry = "SELECT * FROM {table} limit %d offset %d"

In [10]: qry.format(**dict(table='my_table')) %(10, 500)
Out[10]: 'SELECT * FROM my_table limit 10 offset 500'
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [53]: my_table = 'table_name'

In [54]: qry
Out[54]: 'SELECT * FROM {table} limit %d offset %d'

In [55]: qry.format(**dict(table=my_table)) %(10, 500)
Out[55]: 'SELECT * FROM table_name limit 10 offset 500'
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a trial per your suggestion and an error I get.

Comment: @SLackA, you missed parameter name `table` in `{table}` - you used `{}`. replace `"SELECT * FROM {} limit %d offset %d"` with `"SELECT * FROM {table} limit %d offset %d"`

Comment: I can see what you are saying but we are having a difference in our code. I need to pass my_table as a variable in `qry.format(**dict(table='my_table')) %(10, 500)`, not as a string. I am trying to do `qry.format(**dict(table=my_table)) %(10, 500)` and getting another error now `28             sql_ct = "SELECT * FROM {table_name} limit %d offset %d"
---> 29             qry = sql_ct.format(**dict(table=table_name)) %(chunk_size, offset)
     30             df_piece = psql.read_sql_query(qry, connection)
     31 

KeyError: 'table_name'`